# Sum of all divisors: Any way to optimize this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This code will calculate the sum of all divisors of a given number. It runs pretty well already, my question is: Can I optimize it even more and is there maybe a better algorithm for this?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

typedef high_resolution_clock hr_clock;

void friendNumbers(int max);
inline int sumOfDivisors(int* n);

int main()
{
    auto max = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the maximum Number: " << endl;
    cin >> max;

    hr_clock::time_point t1 = hr_clock::now();
    friendNumbers(max);
    hr_clock::time_point t2 = hr_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "The program took " << duration << " milliseconds to complete." << endl;
}

//Here I check, if sum1 and sum2 are friend numbers
//(explanation beneath) and print them out
void friendNumbers(int max)
{   
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    for(int i = 2; i != max; ++i) {
        auto sum1 = sumOfDivisors(&i);
        if(i < sum1) continue;
        auto sum2 = sumOfDivisors(&sum1);
        if(i == sum2 && sum1 != sum2) {
            cout << sum1 << " | " << sum2 << endl;
        }
    }
}

//This function returns the sum of divisors of n
inline int sumOfDivisors(int* n)
{
    auto sum = 1;
    auto border = round(sqrt(*n)+1);
    for(int i = 2; i < border; ++i)
        if(*n % i == 0 && i*i != *n)
            sum += i + (*n / i);
    return sum;
}
```

With the sum of the divisors I calculate friend numbers, eg. 220 and 284 because the sum of all divisors of 220 equals 284 and the other way round.

Comment: For feedback on working code, please post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `int max` = merry hell.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Should I move this question then?

Comment: @Bathsheba What do you mean?

Comment: @AProgrammer: You might find yourself porting this to a platform where `min` and `max` are macros, plus you've obliterated your global namespace by bringing in the whole of `std`. Nice.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Not only is `max` a name used inside `namespace std`, but on Windows, it's a macro.  Which will break your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, guys! Yes, I'm on Linux right now, so nothing happened.

Comment: For the general case, you can optimize a lot in `sumOfDivisors`. Instead of this algorithm, factorize the number, then use the factorization to generate all divisors. You may want to ask this question on math.stackexchange, like "which is the fastest algorithm for `sumOfDivisors`?"

Comment: Don't pass by pointer.  In your `sumOfDivisors`, pass the parameter by value.  Passing by value can use processor registers so the cost is not significant.  Passing by pointer means that the pointer must be dereferenced before extracting the value.  This is minimally an extra strep (on some processor, it requires loading the address, then dereferencing the address, a two step process).

Comment: @geza, I'm definitely keeping that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You were absolutely right! Gained 50ms on average

Comment: Try calculating `n%i` and `n/i` before the `if` statement in `sumOfDivisors` and store into const variables. A division operation produces a remainder value.  Maybe the compiler can optimize this and thus only perform one division.  Your posted code performs 2 divisions, one for remainder and the other for division.

Comment: Also, instead of using `auto` for variable declarations, consider using `const *type*`.  For values that won't change, a `const` specifier may help the compiler to perform better optimization.

Comment: Do you have optimization enabled? I ask this because `int *` or `int` should not matter at all. The other thing you should do is use `int` for border. Currently it is a floating point variable.

Comment: Just for your information - I'll be unable to respond to you guys for a few hours.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Thank's for the tips, will apply them to my code, when I'm back!

Comment: @geza Thank's for pointing that out! Yes, I compile with g++ and flag -O3

Comment: Doesn't that return the wrong sum if `n` is a perfect square?

Comment: Then something is not OK, maybe your time measurement. Passing `n` as a pointer should not slow down your code at all, when optimization is on. Of course, it is better when it is not a pointer, but for speed, it has a very-very small influence.

Comment: read this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-sum-divisors-divisors-natural-number/

Comment: @rici It shouldn't, at least not up to n = 100000. I did not test the ones after that.

Comment: @geza Well, time measurement can vary, I tested them both 3 times and the best with pointers and n = 1000000 was 2.678s and without pointers 2.630s

Comment: @TanujYadav That's a very interesting read. Also, it uses a different approach, so I'll try to implement that tomorrow.

Comment: I see. It is 1.7%, maybe if your numbers are small, it can happen. Yes, that approach is the same I recommended you, it factorizes the number.

Comment: @AProgrammer: It reports that sumOfDivisors(4) and sumOfDivisors(9) are both 1, which is not correct. (The result should be 3 and 4, respectively). (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/751beb8ecece32b5). No need to go up to 100,000.

Comment: @rici Looking through the algorithm again, I somehow messed up in implementing the case where i*i == n. Thanks for pointing this out, I only looked at the correctness of the amicable numbers, not at the sum itself. But, now that I corrected this issue, I somehow gained an extra 200ms. Is it faster to split if statements? So instead of if(a>b && c>d) using if(a>b) { if(c>d) {}}

Comment: @geza By using prime factorization, it's almost twice as fast for 1000000! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Conclusion: It seems like splitting if statements really helps: I splitted both if statements in sumOfDivisors and friendNumbers and I'm now at 2.450s instead of 2.780 (on Windows now). This is with the old algorithm and the fix for the perfect squares.